# Getting page by GET, then submiting form

Tags: php, file, curl

I need to get one page (can be cURL, or filegetcontent), get some info from it, then submit form on same page. I don't want to reload page, becouse some things will change. How to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a tool like Mechanize but it's not available for php. There's a [discussion of alternatives on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize).

Comment: Looks harder than i thought, but maybe some of those scripts will help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/) has some really usefull page grabbing & form submitting functions that could be usefull for this.