# Get the URL of a page after a Javascript redirection windows location How to i Src LInk

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, curl

Example this link after paste on browser address bar after redirect of windows.location=
1: main link `http://example.com/v?id=xxxxxxx&itag=36`
after redirect show like this
2:reidrect link `https://r10---sn-4wg7en7l.c.docs.google.com`
how to i get 2nd link for iframe src please any one help on this

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338151/how-do-i-get-the-final-redirected-canonical-url-of-a-website-using-php

Comment: @mario.klump Dear how can i use it on this link please tell me about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the url of your page with `window.location.href` in javascript or get the previous page with `document.referrer`
In PHP you can get the current page with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and the previous page with `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

Comment: can you make it for me i'm not a developer please help to create full code