# parse pdf after downloading it from website

Tags: php, pdf, curl

there is one website which is providing case studies to download. 
In that website i have to first login. Than search for the pdf using one form like selecting dates, type etc.. and than it gives list of pdfs. so on clicking the link it opens the pdf.

Now what i want to do is, automatize this process. I will have one interface to directly select the dates, types etc.. and than it directly prompts me to save the excel file.

Using php i want to automatize the above given process and once i open the pdf. i want to parse the pdf and than copy the selected items in csv.

can anyone tell me how to do all this using php..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be two questions.

The answer to the first part of your question can be found in the SO question:  [Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize)

The answer for the second part of your question can be found in the SO question: [Is there a PDF parser for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251956/is-there-a-pdf-parser-for-php)