# curl to submit post data to inputs only appearing with form submission

Tags: php, curl

I'm writing a crawler in PHP that will enter data into my website. I need to submit data in order to my inputs to display on the page (they're not just hidden). Normally, there is an AJAX process that runs on a button click to display these inputs.

I have returned an HTML doc with these inputs in there; however, my problem is that I can't curl again with my data before these inputs go away. I've tried using curl_multi_exec and it doesn't seem to help.

Also, all of this is at the same URL (form action and form I want to submit).

Answer (score 1):

For Ruby or Perl, the Mechanize library is great for this scenario. For PHP, we want to find  a framework library similar on PHP, which leads to this Q/A:

[Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize)

Enjoy.

Comment: I've never written this sort of script in another language. Would you say doing this is easier or better in Ruby or Perl?

Comment: As someone equally comfortable in PHP/Ruby/Java, I would say Mechanize is "full" featured as it does simplistic Javascript parsing to do this. That said, if I was just a PHP guy, I would try the Simpletest solution to see if it fit my needs. Back in the day when I needed to scrape websites, I also used chickenfoot: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/uid/chickenfoot/