# php script to logon to twitter account with proxy

Tags: php, twitter

Anyone know how to write a php script that logs on to Twitter behind a proxy? Something like what tweet adder and twtdominator does. I've tried searching on google but have come up with nothing. I am aware this question is very general i don't know what else to describe this. Just point me in the right direction. thanks.

Comment: dont they have an api ?

Comment: yes. i know how to logon via api....but how to do so behind a proxy is my question.

Comment: twitter is irrelevant then its how do i use curl? or what ever your using with a proxy ?

Comment: so your saying simply enable the proxy via curl and then logon through twitter api normally??

Comment: correct, assuming i understand the question ;)

Comment: how to test if you are successfully using the proxy to access twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like http://www.simpletest.org/en/browser_documentation.html (via [Is there a PHP equivalent of Perl's WWW::Mechanize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize))