# Parsing Javascript generated table with simple html dom

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table, simple-html-dom

I have a question. It is possible to parse Javascript generated html tables? Because I tried with simple html dom, and I got a blank page for result every time.

Here is the parsed website:

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="informations.php" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

// Draw table from 'jsData' array of objects
function drawTable(tbody) {
    var tr, td;
    tbody = document.getElementById(tbody);
    // loop through data source
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = tbody.insertRow(tbody.rows.length);
        tr.setAttribute("class", "f1");
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i][1];
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.innerHTML = data[i][2];
td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = data[i][3];
        td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = data[i][4];
td = tr.insertCell(tr.cells.length);
        td.setAttribute("align", "center");
        td.innerHTML = data[i][5];

    }
}

//-->
</script>


<table>
<tr>
<td><h2>Informations</h2></td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="sortable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Information</th>
<th>Birthday</th>
<th>Postcode</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="FData"></tbody>
</table>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
drawTable("FData");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no problem with classic tables, but with js generated tables I got blank page for result everytime. What is the solution?

Comment: How are you sending the table back to PHP so it can parse it?

Comment: I try to parse with simple html dom, I set the url of this file, and I try to parse the td-s at simple html dom.

Comment: Javascript is run in the browser. If you just download the URL into PHP, it doesn't run Javascript, because PHP is not a browser.

Comment: And what can I do now? How can I parse this table?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199045/is-there-a-php-equivalent-of-perls-wwwmechanize

Comment: You could run it through phantomjs and parse the output

Answer (score 0):

### try this code in your JS function.

// Find a  element with id="myTable":

`var table = document.getElementById("myTable");`

// Create an empty  element and add it to the 1st position of the table:

`var row = table.insertRow(0);`

// Insert new cells ( elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" 
 element:

`var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);`

// Add some text to the new cells:

`cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";`

Comment: I don't understand this. If I put this extra table before my table then my table will be able to parse? I see just your code will put an extra table before my table, not?

Comment: please assign ID in your table tag. like this: `<table id="myTable">`